# How to define a javascript function inside HTML and make it able to accept values from user

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do whitebox testing of a code and I have to create a function which can accept values from the user. I used a template for creating a submit form and then I defined a function for the user to accept values and then pass it to the function, which is in another .js file.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Device motion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DeviceMotion3D.js">


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Passing(){
    alert("called");
               var c = document.getElementById("textX").value;
                var d = document.getElementById("textY").value();
                var e = document.getElementById("multiX").value();
                var f = document.getElementById("multiY").value();
                alert("c:"+c +"d:"+ d +"e:"+e+"f:" +f);
               // DeviceMotion3D(c,d,e,f);

                 }

                 </script>
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <div id="logo">

            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">

                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="contact.html">Device motion</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div>
            <div class="body" id="contact">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div class="body">
                        <img src="images/chair-small.png" alt="Img">
                        <div class="contact">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="main">
                    <h1>Cube</h1>
                    <p>
                        This cube does this. This file does that. These values do all this
                        </p>
                    <form action="Cube.html" method="post" onsubmit="Passing();">
                <form>
                        <label>X axis angle</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="X" id="textX">
                        <label>Y axis angle</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="Y" id="textY">
                        <label>multiplying factor x</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="x" id="multiX">
                        <label>multiplying factor y</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="y" id="multiY">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn1" onclick="Passing();" >
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .js file which contains a function for which whitebox testing has to be done:

```
var DeviceMotion3D=function(_param)
{
alert("c:"+_param.c +"d:"+ _param.d +"e:"+_param.e+"f:" +_param.f);
    var _obj=_param;
    var _v=new Object;
    var _p=new Object;
    var flag=0;
    _v.enabled=true;
    var b1=_param.c;
    var b2=_param.d;
    var c1=_param.e;
    var c2=_param.f;

    _p.init=function()
    {
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", _p.orientationSence,false );
    }
    _p.oyAng=0;
    _p.oxAng=0;
    _p.orientationSence=function()
    {
        if(_v.enabled)
            {
                var xAng=(event.b1)*c1 ;
                var yAng=(event.b2)*c2 ;
                _obj.element.style.webkitTransform = "rotateX("+ (xAng) +"deg) rotateY("+ (360-yAng) +"deg)";
                _p.oxAng=xAng;
                _p.oyAng=yAng;
            }
    }
    _p.init();
    return _v;
}
```

But this is not working. I used a alert to know if it is going to the function Passing(), but no alert is shown so all the values remain undefined. So please help with this.

Comment: Why are you using the form and the submit? Just the onclick would probably be easier.

Comment: I tried to use onclick but it is also not working.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look valid - I see there are two `<form >` open tags in a row?

Comment: And the variables which I am passing are the angles that the device throws at every moment. And the other two variables are the multiplying factor. These angles and multiplying factors determine the speed with which the cube will rotate.(Which is another js file)

Comment: Not sure about this, but get rid of the semi-colons after Passing() in the onsubmit and onclick calls.

Comment: Oh sorry!! That happened while I was trying different combinations. I have removed that extra form. Still it did not work

Comment: Tried removing semi colons. Not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example. User enters two numbers in text fields, then clicks button and third text field if filled with sum of numbers user entered.

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jsc2.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Calculator</h3>
        <div style="border:none;height:130px;" id="okvir">
            <form action="#">
            First Number: <input type="text" id="num1" name="FirstNumber"> 
            <br /><br />
            Second Number: <input type="text" id="num2" name="SecondNumber">
            <br /><br />
            Sum: <input type="text" name="Result" id="result"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="button" class="button1" onClick="add();" value="Sum" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is .js:

```
function add(){
    var a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    var res = a + b;
    document.getElementById('result').value=res;
}
```

var a = **document.getElementById('num1').value;** is used for getting data from user and
**document.getElementById('result').value**=res; for setting data in HTML from function.

**onClick="add();"** is used for calling function in HTML.

input type="button" class="button1" **onClick="add();"** value="Sum"

I hope this helps you and you can use it in your code. Best of luck.

**Added after comments:**

Ok, i modified your code after comments. I've deleted some lines for better view. Hope this helps. :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Device motion</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="DeviceMotion3D.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function Passing(){
    alert("called in HTML");
               var c = document.getElementById("textX").value;
                var d = document.getElementById("textY").value;
                var e = document.getElementById("multiX").value;
                var f = document.getElementById("multiY").value;
                alert("c:"+c +"d:"+ d +"e:"+e+"f:" +f);
                DeviceMotion3D(c,d,e,f);
                 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>              
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Cube</h1>
        <p>This cube does this. This file does that. These values do all this</p>
        <!-- <form action="Cube.html" method="post" onclick="Passing();"></form>-->
        <form action="#">
            <label>X axis angle</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="X" id="textX">
            <label>Y axis angle</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="Y" id="textY">
            <label>multiplying factor x</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="x" id="multiX">
            <label>multiplying factor y</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="y" id="multiY">
        </form>
        <br />
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="button" class="button1" onClick="Passing();" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

.js file:

```
function DeviceMotion3D(pc,pd,pe,pf){
alert("called in funct");
alert("c:"+ pc +"d:"+ pd +"e:"+ pe +"f:" + pf);
var _obj = {
        c:pc,
        d:pd,
        e:pe,
        f:pf
    };
    alert("called in funct as object");
    alert("c:"+_obj.c +"d:"+ _obj.d +"e:"+_obj.e+"f:" +_obj.f);
}
```

Now, Passing is called first. Then in it, DeviceMotion3D is called with parameters. If you want to skip calling Passing, replace

```
<input type="button" class="button1" onClick="Passing();" value="Submit" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" class="button1" onClick="DeviceMotion3D();" value="Submit" />
```

delete script for passing in HTML or put it in comment brackets. And change .js:

```
function DeviceMotion3D(){
alert("called in funct");
               var pc = document.getElementById("textX").value;
                var pd = document.getElementById("textY").value;
                var pe = document.getElementById("multiX").value;
                var pf = document.getElementById("multiY").value;
alert("c:"+ pc +"d:"+ pd +"e:"+ pe +"f:" + pf);
var _obj = {
        c:pc,
        d:pd,
        e:pe,
        f:pf
    };
    alert("called in funct as object");
    alert("c:"+_obj.c +"d:"+ _obj.d +"e:"+_obj.e+"f:" +_obj.f);
}
```

Best of luck. :)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer. I tried to define function Passing in the js file only and commented in the html page. But its still not working. Not able to undertsand the problem. Like it is not even accepting the values as otherwise the alert "called" would have appeared.

Comment: Hi Just saw. I had to close script tag for js file in that line only and now that function is getting called but it is not able to pass values further to the js file. So alert in html page gives values which are entered by the user but alert for the js file give undefined values.

Comment: I've added more code in post. Hope it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rod..:)will try this solution.. Hope this one works!!